# ess - starting directory

Tags: ess

I use ess to run R and have encountered an annoying change that now when I start an R process with ess it defaults to starting in what is apparently the root of the project not the directory of the file in the buffer I'm in. For example if I'm editing a file in an R package that is in the `~/projects/my_package/tests/` directory and press `C-c r` I am prompted with:

```
"R starting project directory? ~/projects/my/package/"
```

But a previous behaviour which I think is more intuitive was for the default to start in the directory that the file i saved (`~/projects/my_package/tests/`).

I read this: https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Customizing-startup and interpret that ess determines the working directory in some way that I am not happy with. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you linked is unfortunately a little bit outdated.  Currently, it says:

1. If the variable `ess-directory-function` stores the name of a function, the value returned by this function is used.  The default for this variable is nil.
2. Otherwise, if the variable `ess-directory` stores the name of a directory (ending in a slash), this value is used.  The default for this variable is nil.
3. Otherwise, the working directory of the current buffer is used.

On the other hand, ESS currently defines `inferior-ess--get-startup-directory` as:

```lisp
(defun inferior-ess--get-startup-directory ()
  "Return a startup directory."
  (let ((dir (or (when (boundp 'ess-startup-directory)
                   (if (symbolp ess-startup-directory)
                       (symbol-value ess-startup-directory)
                     ess-startup-directory))
                 (and ess-startup-directory-function
                      (funcall ess-startup-directory-function))
                 (when-let ((proj (project-current)))
                   (ess--project-root proj))
                 default-directory)))
    (directory-file-name dir)))
```

(`ess-directory` is an alias for `ess-startup-directory` and `ess-directory-function` an alias for `ess-startup-directory-function`.)

In other words:

- Steps 1. and 2. are swapped; and
- Prior to step 3., `project-current` is consulted if it can be used instead of `default-directory`.

If you want to prevent `project-current` from being consulted, you can define your own `ess-startup-directory-function` that always returns `default-directory`:

```lisp
(defun my-ess-startup-directory-function ()
  "Force ESS to use `default-directory' as its startup directory."
  default-directory)

(setq ess-startup-directory-function 'my-ess-startup-directory-function)
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem too, but now it doesn't seem to work anymore. Probably the ESS code has changed again?

Comment: It took me a while to implement in my config but today it is working for me do as d125q suggests in the last code block. Now when I ask emacs to start R, the working directory defaults to the parent directory of the file in the buffer or the directory I'm in if the buffer is a dired buffer. Perfect!

Comment: @pglpm See the help for `ess-startup-directory`. The documentation listed above is incomplete - ESS now checks to see if you are in a "project" before deciding which directory to use, that might be causing your problem